# How can I intercept requests against file and change them to http protocol?

Tags: electron

In Electron, is it possible to intercept requests against file:/// and redirect them to http?

I have checked the Electron [protocol](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md) page, but it's not obvious if this is supported or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [protocol.registerHttpProtocol](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md#protocolregisterhttpprotocolscheme-handler-completion) with the scheme `file` to intercept `file:` requests, and instead make an HTTP request.

Example (*untested*):

```
const {app, protocol} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.on('ready', () => {
  protocol.registerHttpProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(8)
    callback({url: 'http://example.com/' + url)})
  }, (error) => {
    if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
})
```

Note: this sample may need refining as the file path may include the drive letter, which would be invalid for an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way I was able to address this and interestingly the word "intercept" in the question has a lot to do with it :)

There is a function [interceptHttpProtocol()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md#protocolintercepthttpprotocolscheme-handler-completion) on the protocol object you can use.

Sample code:

```
app.on("ready", () => {
    protocol.interceptHttpProtocol("http", function(request, callback) {
    var parsedUri = url.parse(request.url);

    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, parsedUri.pathname);
    request.url = "file://" + filePath; 

    callback(request);
  });

  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost/index.html");
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Unable to replicate. Attempting to change the `interceptHttpProtocol` `url` to use `file://` only returns `ERR_INVALID_URL`. What electron version are you using?